# How to set up OpenGL environment in Windows 7?

Tags: opengl

I am new to OpenGL. I have to develop a simple 3D application. I read from Google that I have to install GLUT and OpenGL. Is that right? Can you tell what exactly should I install?
Any link for proper download is appreciated.

Comment: http://www.arcsynthesis.org/gltut/

Comment: If you want to use GLUT, you can. This is not a requirement, but might be a decent start. A basic OpenGL library already comes with your OS and extensions can be loaded with a library like GLEW. Other than that the book/tutorials KillianDS links to is excellent.

Comment: @Androiduser searching for any "OpenGL tutorial", reading any OpenGL book will tell you a basic "how to set up an OpenGL window", most often for both windows an X. I didn't vote to close, but this question showed no research effort at all (which if you look closely is on the pop up box of the votedown button). This would be a good question if this wasn't explained a thousand times already or you had a very specific question of something non-trivial in the setup.

Comment: ok . i found out many links but nothing worked thats why posteb

Comment: Then you should ask a question with example code and a clear explanation of what is not working. That's how SO works ;).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Google that I have to install GLUT and

You don't need GLUT necessarily. A lot of tutorials use it, though.

> OpenGL. Is that right?

Well, OpenGL is mostly an API to the drivers. So what you actually need are the drivers for your graphics processor directly from the vendor. The drivers Windows7 installs automatically lack modern OpenGL support.

So just head over to http://intel.com or http://amd.com or http://nvidia.com, depending on your GPU, and download the drivers for from their site directly and install them.

What I highly recommend is getting GLEW: http://glew.sf.net – it makes things to much easier in the long run. Especially if you want to do anything beyond OpenGL-1.1 you'll have to use the so called *extension system* which is a bit tedious to use directly. GLEW hides this all behind a single function call to `glewInit()`, once you've got a OpenGL context.

Comment: As for the last part, I personally have encountered some annoying issues with `glew`. For example, until 1.6 it had errors in the API, it mixes function pointers and forward declarations. I prefer `glload` from the [unofficial OpenGL SDK](http://glsdk.sourceforge.net/docs/html/index.html).